# How to display a character based on coordinate where it should be?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

How to display a matrix of character based on the coordinate that we give?

This is what i have tried but it only display back the coordinate. I have no ideas to read the coordinate and display the character.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a coordinate: ");

String coordinate = input.nextLine();
String[] parts = coordinate.split(" ");

// if input is (x, y) 
// then parts[0] is "(x"
// and parts[1] is " y)"

String x = parts[0].trim().substring(1).trim();
String y = parts[1].trim().substring(0, parts[1].trim().length() - 1).trim();

System.out.println("x: " + x + "\ny: " + y);
}
```

if the input:

kfc

1 2 //the row and column for first kfc branch

0 1 //the row and column for second kfc branch

mcd

0 2 //the row and column for first mcd branch

1 1 //the row and column for second mcd branch

the output should be: // in matrix

0 k m // k represent kfc locates at 0 1 and m represent mcd at 0 2

0 m k // k represent kfc locates at 1 2 and m represent mcd at 1 1

Comment: Can you explain why this input should give this output

Comment: What Matrix? What exactly is in the Matrix? Coordinates would relate to x & y (Row & Column). Why are you using the **substring()** method? The **split()** method should be good enough. The provided coordinates I suspect would be the same as providing Row and Column Index values therefore the supplied values need to be checked against matrix extents otherwise an Out Of Bounds exception will occur. Your input output example is meaningless. A more detailed explanation is required.